# ¿Hay alguna macro/variable para el numero del versionamiento en Github Actions?

Tags: yaml, github-actions, integracion-continua, despliegue-continuo

Estoy realizando un script de Actions para automatizar la generacion de un archivo PDF con una aplicacion que hize con Node.js. El comando `npm start` genera dentro de un folder `build/` el archivo `cv.pdf` este es mi script que nesesito arreglar.

```
name: Create Release
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    name: Curriculum generation
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: "20"

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Create output directory
        run: mkdir -p build

      - name: Initialize application
        run: npm start

      - name: Upload PDF
        id: pdf-upload
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: curriculum
          path: build/cv.pdf
          overwrite: true
          retention-days: 90

      - name: Create Release
        id: create_release
        uses: actions/create-release@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          tag_name: V${{ github.ref }}
          release_name: Release ${{ github.ref }}
          body: |
            Changes in this Release
            - Updated fields
          draft: false
          prerelease: false
    
      - name: Upload Asset
        id: upload-asset
        uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          upload_url: ${{ steps.pdf-upload.outputs.artifact-url }}
          asset_path: ./build/cv.pdf
          asset_name: curriculum.pdf
          asset_content_type: application/pdf
```

Intente resolver esto con un comando en `awk` pero falle miserablemente, asi que encontre este [ejemplo](https://github.com/actions/create-release?tab=readme-ov-file#example-workflow---create-a-release) donde se usa `actions/create-release@v1` y utiliza un parametro peculiar `github.ref` el cual ya fue [bloqueado](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-03-23-block-ambiguous-branch-and-tag-names/). Yo queria saber como puedo hacer que este script automaticamente deduzca la version usando la API de Github. Como por ejemplo.. si no hay version definina que le ponga 1 y si ya existe, entonces que le ponga un decimal tipo version 1.1 y asi hacia adelante. No se como este hecho, no se si es una variable/macro o alguna funcionalidad que hay que activar para hacerse. Esto es algo tan comun que me parece extraño que no encuente algo asi en su [referencia](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context).

Estoy aprendiendo y nesesito ayuda con esto. Quedo atento a sus comentarios

Comment: otro error que estoy teniendo es que el paso `Upload PDF` se genera el cv en `build/cv.pdf` pero en el campo `Upload Asset` no lo adhiere a la pagina de Releases pero eso sera para otra pregunta

Comment: son 2 actions? uno para crear un tag/version y otro para documentar la version actual ( crear pdf) ?

Comment: @aloMalbarez buenas es un solo script que intenta deducir la version y la publica como release

Comment: 1/ segun entiendo el script que mencionas toma la version desde un ref tag, el ref tag lo podes crear con [`npm version`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-version) que modifica el campo version en el `package.json` y arma un commit del tag salvo que le digas que no; 
si usas el `patch`  como cache buster por ej `npm --no-git-tag-version version patch` ( bumpea el patch sin crear un tag  )

Comment: 2/ para generar documentación o archivos intermedios que incluyan la versión del package sin considerar los ref/tags podes hacer un import x ej desde `./src/scripts/gen-version-templates.js` -> `const cfg = require('../../package.json');console.log(cfg.version);`

Comment: @aloMalbarez aunque parece interesante el metodo con node realmente estoy buscando la forma de hacerlo usando github. Si conoces alguna manera, considera escribir una respuesta